# Outlook 2016 Account Transfer

Tags: email-client, microsoft-outlook-2016

Is there any way to fully export Outlook 2016 accounts to a file so they can be easily moved to another system ?
I have to manage quite a few email accounts for work and it's becoming a major pain . Especially when I have to prepare another machine or reload the Windows on one. I tried using the import/export function built in but that's extremely limited and of no use in this case.

Even having those Outlook run on a different partition than the system partition would be nice , maybe then all I'd have to do is install Outlook after reinstalling Windows and not type like a robot 10+ account info and passwords , then wait for Outlook 2016 to reprocess all the data.

OneNote can move its files with great ease and good security and I was hoping to find a similar procedure for Outlook but my Google Fu has failed and Microsoft doesn't have any official solution .

Also we're dealing with legal info on sensitive cases and we simply can't risk our info to sit on the cloud and MS/Google/Whomever to hand it over to a malevolent party because Judge Lapdog from Lower Warlordetto sent them a napkin written subpoena.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. Close the outlook client on the actual system
2. Copy the `.ost` file in the follow path:

> C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook

4. Start the outlook client in the new system and configure it to use it, close the Client after a 10 seconds.
5. Copy the old `.ost` file to the new system and replace the new `.ost` file, changue the name of the old `.ost` if is necesary.
6. Start the outlook client on the new machine again.

Important: don't start the outlook client of the old system after copy the old `.ost` file.

Comment: That did not work.

Comment: Would you explaind why doesnt work? Do you you have any question?

Comment: I followed the instructions to the letter, copied the .ost and Outlook didn't picked up the new account.

Is there a tutorial on the subject or a video ?